# Android - Calculate duration that user hasn't been using the applcation

Tags: android

Is there anyway to find out how long the app has been closed since the last use? I am writing an application that manipulates data depends on how long user hasn't been using the application. For example: For every hour that the user doesn't visit the app, data called "score" reduces by 10. So if user hasn't opened the app for 2 hours, "score" reduces by 20.

So I am just wondering if it is possible, and if yes, how can I achieve it?

Thanks!

Comment: can you store a time stamp when the user closes the app which you can compare to the current time when the app is opened again?

Comment: How do you define `not using the app`? Press back on main `Activity`? Or press home key? Or kill the process?

Comment: @Alfie good idea, i will try that

Comment: @shhp I would say when user closes the app (press home/user uses another app/user goes back to main screen....), basically "not using the app" will be anything makes the app go away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `onPause` store system time in your `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefs.edit().putLong("last_used",System.currentTimeMillis()).commit();
```

and in your `onResume` read the value "last_used" and do the calculation:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
long lastTime = prefs.getLong("last_used");
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

//Now do the calculations as you like
```

Comment: Thank for your suggestion, I will try this and report back how it goes!